# Why my IE8 won't play flash video and keep displaying "access denied error" message

Tags: internet-explorer-8, html5-video, flash

I am working on HTML5 video features. My development environment is Windows 7, WAMPserver, and five browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, safari, and IE8). I think i have did it well because the video run smoothly on all browsers except for IE8. Since i know IE8 doesn't support HTML5 video i already include a fallback function in my script and using JWplayer.js to play the video with flash player. I've configured my .htaccess and my flash player Global Security Settings as well. But IE8 still won't play the video. it shows the flash player anyway. but it keep showing me the following error:

```
Video not found or access denied: video/stay_creative.mp4
```

This is my code :

```
<video width="500" height="280" controls>
                <source src="video/stay_creative.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
                <source src="video/stay_creative.webmvp8.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
                <source src="video/stay_creative.theora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
                <!-- fall to flash : for IE lt v 9 -->
                <object width="500" height="280" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/player.swf">
                    <param name="movie" value="js/player.swf">
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                    <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=video/stay_creative.mp4">
                </object>
            </video>
```

This is my .htaccess:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Any advice guys? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the controlbar part.

```
<param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=video/stay_creative.mp4">
```

to this code, and see if it works

```
<param name="flashvars" value="file=video/stay_creative.mp4">
```